# CloudWatch agent on windows stops sending IIS logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

At work we are running a couple of Ec2 instances in Amazon with Windows Server 2012 and IIS.

Setting up the IIS logs and eventlogs etc to be sent to CloudWatch works perfectly.

The problem comes when i add my own things to the IIS log that i want to have on each line of accesslog, IIS then renames the logfile to "date_x.log" and when it has the "_x" in the end of the filename, the Ec2Config service does not roll over to the next logfile, it stops at 23:59 PM every day. If i restart the Ec2Config windows service it picks up the new one, so i set up a scheduled task and had it running over the weekend but when i came back to work now on monday morning, it had stopped sunday night at 23:59 pm. Now i can no longer restart the service to pick up the new logfile.

If i change back to having no custom items in the IIS log it works perfectly fine, but this will not work for us, we need the custom items.

Adding a filter in the JSON config file has no effect.

Any idea on what is going on and how i can solve it?

UPDATE: After leaving it running with this issue going, it appears that the agent does not stop sending logs completely, but instead it skips every second day or so.